# Is there a way to read only a single integer from a line of integers in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

My ultimate aim is this: Given a list of numbers, create map where the key is the number and the value is it's frequency in the given list.

Let's say I have an input which I want to supply to my program via the standard input. It is a single line which contain a certain number of integers. Example:

```
 12 1 4 5 10 87
```

Is there a way by which I can read only one integer at a time? As of now, I have been taking the input in one go, splitting it based on the space delimitter and then converting string to integer for each element like this:

```
arr = input().split() //Take input
myArr = list(map(lambda x : int(x), arr)) //Map each string element to it's integer counterpart.
```

Since all I want to do is create a map, reading the entire input at once and having it in memory is unnecessary to me.
Is there a better way to do this by which I can read only 1 integer at a time and build my map rather than having to read the list completely at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Counter creates a dict with number of occurences. You can do like below.

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(map(int, input().split())))
```

Output:

```
12 1 4 5 10 87
Counter({12: 1, 1: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 10: 1, 87: 1})
```